# Selenium Webdriver + geckodriver + python 2.6.6 + Firefox on RedHat 6.8 fails to open browser

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, redhat, geckodriver

I am having issues with successfully launching a Firefox Browser using the Selenium Webdriver for python. I have the following setup parameters:

```
Selenium Webdriver 3.4.3
Python 2.6.6
geckodriver-v0.18.0-linux64.tar.gz
firefox-45.0.1.1.el6.x86_64
```

Now, the geckodriver file is unzipped and is currently in `/usr/local/bin` directory with rwx all the way across:

```
rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7129173 Jul 26 14:42 geckodriver
```

I have updated the `.bash_profile` to include the path as:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

The script that I am using is from the readme within the Selenium-3.4.3 directory "README.rst".

Scriptname:   `first_selenium_script.py`

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

So, the results are as follows,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first_selenium_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-   packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",   line 152, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site- packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site- packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site- packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a  matching set of capabilities
```

Any thoughts please . . . Thanks.

Comment: Have you logged out and back in to start using your new .bash_profile file ?  You could try putting the geckodriver in /usr/bin/geckodriver instead, I know that's where I have it.

Comment: Hmm... And I just found this comment in the wild: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884#issuecomment-296501573  Looks like the most recent version of geckodriver may not work with FireFox 45.  Try upgrading FireFox, if you can.

Comment: Searching the net a little more, I found, alimp5's solution @ [link] https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884

>>>   ` from selenium import webdriver

    caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX ...
    caps["marionette"] = False  ...

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps) ...

    driver.get("http://www.google.com")  ...

    print driver.title  ...

    driver.quit()`  <<<

Which worked . . .  I don't understand why yet, but I will keep reading until I do.

Comment: Awesome if that works!  Good job.  :)

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan.

Comment: No problem!  Consider posting your comment as an answer and accepting it.  This way, people will know that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I am almost positive that my comment is correct - a version incompatibility between FireFox 45 and geckodriver 0.18.  According to the [geckodriver page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases):

> **v0.18.0**
>
> geckodriver now recommends Firefox 53 and greater

It looks like FireFox 45 may be incompatible with geckodriver.  Geckodriver was [initially released](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.1.0) on Apr 9, 2015, and Firefox 45 [was released](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar) on March 8, 2015.

So while there might be some chance of getting it to work on an old geckodriver, the best option would really be to update FireFox to >= v53.